# Monodroid .jar Binding Issue

Tags: facebook, binding, xamarin.android, xamarin

I'm trying to fix some binding errors with the Facebook SDK.  I have two functions that have the same name "setPermissions" in the same class.  The `IntPtr` generated by the `Monodroid` binding generator is creating the same variable name for each `id_setPermissions_Ljava_util_List_`.  I need to fix this by changing one of the functions to a different name so that the binding generator won't create the same variable name.

I'm stuck when it comes to figuring out what I need to set in the `Metadata.xml` file.  I have this so far:

```
<attr path="/api/package[@name='com.facebook']/class[@name='Session.OpenRequest']/method[@name='setPermissions']" name="managedName">OpenRequestSetPermission</attr>
```

The problem with the above line will change both functions to be named the same and not fixing the issue I'm having with the generated `static IntPtr id_setPermissions_Ljava_util_List_;`

They have different return types, but I do not know if that can be any help in determining one function over the other in the `Metadata.xml`.

Comment: Could you give the appropriate snippet of \obj\Debug\api.xml this might help to find a way to distinguish the functions.

Answer (score 0):

There are some ways to deterimne function by name and it signature.
For example if you have functions

```
int remove(int a);
int remove(int a, object b);
int remove(float a, object b);
```

you can find second one by

```
<attr path="/api/package[@name='org.mapsforge.android.maps.overlay']/class[@name='OverlayList']/method[@name='remove' and count(parameter)=2 and parameter[1][@type='int']]" name="managedReturn">Java.Lang.Object</attr>
```

maybe there are way to filter function by return type, sadly i don't know that.