# Binding error using Xamarin Android due to overload method

Tags: c#, java, android, xamarin.android, xamarin

I'm having a problem compiling a binding project using Xamarin. The original jar file has an interface that contains two methods that are named equally but receive different parameter (an overload method). When the binding project translates jar file to C# code, it results in some errors due this overloading.

If I change the method name using the Metadata.xml file, it changes both name methods but it ends in the same errors.

Here is the original interface code in jar file:

```
 public abstract interface MitControllerListener
{
  public abstract void setMITCardInformation(MITCardInformation paramMITCardInformation);

  public abstract void setMitError(String paramString, int paramInt);

  public abstract void setResult(String paramString);

  public abstract void setResult(BeanResponseSell paramBeanResponseSell);
}
```

This is the api.xml in the binding project corresponding to the overload method:

```
<method abstract="true" deprecated="not deprecated" final="false" name="setResult" native="false" return="void" static="false" synchronized="false" visibility="public">
<parameter name="p0" type="com.mitec.bean.BeanResponseSell">
</parameter>
</method>
<method abstract="true" deprecated="not deprecated" final="false" name="setResult" native="false" return="void" static="false" synchronized="false" visibility="public">
<parameter name="p0" type="java.lang.String">
</parameter>
```

Comment: What's the error message that you get? Any `BG` warnings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I could make it work  using an additional property in the file Metadata.xml to differentiate one from another method with the same name by the parameter type each method receives:

```
<attr path="/api/package[@name='com.x.controller']/interface[@name='MitControllerListener']/method[@name='setResult' and parameter[1][@type='java.lang.String']]" name="managedName">SetResult2</attr>
```

I base this solution using the idea proposed in one of the responses posted in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14607965/monodroid-jar-binding-issue)